# Filtering by user comments - SQL number of parameters must be between 0 and 65535

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a data table with filter and sorting options. I need to get those users that have in their comments the word 'test' (for example). So I first made a query to get all user_ids where comment body contains the search term. And then used those ids to return only those users.

The problem with this method is that if my databse has millions of records I start getting this error.

> Failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7
>   number of parameters must be between 0 and 65535.

Is there another way I could filter the results?

**users table**

```
id |  username
1     jacko2
2     billyElf
3     crazyJack
```

**user_comments table**

```
id | user_id |    comment_body
1       1         test comment
2       2         another one
3       1         hello world
4       3         testing 123
```

Here is my code so far

```
$search_term = 'test'

$user_ids = query("SELECT user_id FROM user_comments WHERE comment_body LIKE '%$test%'")
$result = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($user_ids)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine the queries into a singe query and use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_comments uc
              WHERE uc.user_id = u.id AND
                    uc.comment_body LIKE ?
             );
```

You want to use `EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`, just in case there are users that have more than one matching comment.

The `?` is a placeholder for passing in a string value (you might really want `CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`.  You should use such parameters to pass in such values, for a variety of reasons:

- It makes the code safe from SQL injection attacks.
- It helps the optimizer (particularly for re-using the query plan).
- It prevents very hard to debug syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must use GROUP_CONCAT

```
$search_term = 'test'

$user_ids = query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) as user_id from user_comments where comment_body like '%$test%'")
$result = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($user_ids)")
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on why OP should use group concat?

Comment: because wee need coma separated for sql in query